# looping a div by using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#LM_MM_Plus_Icon').click(function(){
        $('#LM_MM_New_Div').append($('#LM_MM_Plus_Icon_Block').html());
    });
});
```

In the above function whenever I click on `LM_MM_Plus_Icon` the html in `LM_MM_Plus_Icon_Block` will appended to `LM_MM_New_Div` (which is a empty div).

The user can click any number of times on `LM_MM_Plus_Icon`, so that the html will be appended to `LM_MM_New_Div`. But what I need is every time the user clicks on `LM_MM_Plus_Icon`, a new `LM_MM_New_Div` has to be created and the html to be appended in to it.

Currently all the html is appending to one single `LM_MM_New_Div`.

Comment: What would the additional divs be appended to?

Comment: sorry I didn't get you???

Comment: I mean, what should the newly created divs be append to? `LM_MM_Plus_Icon`? `body`?

Comment: Try this: $("body").append("<div id='LM_MM_New_Div'>"+$('#LM_MM_Plus_Icon_Block').html()+"</div>")

Comment: @ShivaSrikanthThummidi - The OP hasn't stated what they want it appending to and your code will create multiple divs with the same id.

Comment: yes, its right, please use CLASS instead of ID. thanks -Joe

Comment: What's with all the haters and their downvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should :

- clone your `#LM_MM_Plus_Icon_Block` element
- remove its id (to avoir duplicates)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#LM_MM_Plus_Icon').click(function(){
        $('#LM_MM_New_Div').append(
            $('#LM_MM_Plus_Icon_Block')
                .clone()
                .removeAttr('id'));
    });
    $('body').on('click', '.LM_MM_Remove_Icon', function() {
        $(this).closest('.LM_MM_Div').remove();     
    });
});
```

```css
#LM_MM_New_Div {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
#LM_MM_Plus_Icon_Block {
    display: none;
}
.LM_MM_Div {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 3px;
}
#LM_MM_Plus_Icon,
.LM_MM_Remove_Icon {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="LM_MM_Plus_Icon">+</button>

<div id="LM_MM_New_Div"></div>
<div id="LM_MM_Plus_Icon_Block" class="LM_MM_Div">
    Content
    <button class="LM_MM_Remove_Icon">x</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to tell u one thing, the 'LM_MM_Plus_Icon_Block' css i kept 'display:none', so it has to be blocked at the same time.

Comment: Simply use `.removeAttr('id').clone().show()` instead.

Comment: its working but, the new div is getting added only single time...I need any number of times...

Comment: @user2931525 Sorry, I gave you a wrong order : `.clone().removeAttr('id').show()`. (You must remove the id **after** cloning the element)

Comment: Hi Zessx, its working fine....only one more thing I need is after the 'LM_MM_Plus_Icon_Block' html added to 'LM_MM_New_Div', the html has a 'delete_icon'. So if I click on this icon, only that particular 'block' has to be removed, not the entire 'LM_MM_New_Div'. Could you please help me on this also.

Comment: @user2931525 See my edit. Be careful, I added `LM_MM_Remove_Icon` **AND** `LM_MM_Div` classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach instead:

```
function addBlock() {
  var block = $('<div></div>'),
      content = $('#LM_MM_Plus_Icon_Block').html(),
      deleteBtn = $('<button class="LM_MM_Delete">Delete Me</button>');
  block.html(content).append(deleteBtn).appendTo('#container');
}

$('#LM_MM_Plus_Icon').click(addBlock);
$('#container').on('click', '.LM_MM_Delete', function() { $(this).parent().remove(); });
```

---

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YM68Z/

With deletion: http://jsfiddle.net/YM68Z/1/

Comment: what is this '('{element to be added to}')' ???

Comment: I forgot to tell u one thing, the 'LM_MM_Plus_Icon_Block' css i kept 'display:none', so it has to be blocked at the same time.

Comment: For instance, if you are appending it to the body, put 'body' there. If it's going inside a parent container, put the ID of the parent there. As for the 'display:none', it won't affect the new element. Just don't reuse the same ID for the new element. Hold on, I'll make a fiddle.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working example

Comment: sorry... the link is going to your home page.

Comment: Huh? What home page? http://jsfiddle.net/YM68Z/ -- you should see 4 panes. The top left is HTML, bottom left is JavaScript, top right is CSS, and bottom right is the functional example. Click the button that says "+ Add New Block".

Comment: Hi Steve, its working fine....only one more thing I need is after the 'LM_MM_Plus_Icon_Block' html added to 'LM_MM_New_Div', the html has a 'delete_icon'. So if I click on this icon, only that particular 'block' has to be removed, not the entire 'LM_MM_New_Div'. Could you please help me on this also

Comment: I've added a second fiddle. Note how the .on() event handler is constructed. You will need to update this to match your markup. Just calling .click() will not work on these elements, as they do not exist in the DOM at the time the script is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

**You can not use same Id for multiple Div use class instead**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#LM_MM_Plus_Icon').click(function(){
     $('<div class="LM_MM_New_Div" />').append($('#LM_MM_Plus_Icon_Block').html());
     $('<div class="LM_MM_New_Div" />').insertAfter($("body").find(".LM_MM_New_Div:last"));
});});
```

Comment: I forgot to tell u one thing, the 'LM_MM_Plus_Icon_Block' css i kept 'display:none', so it has to be blocked at the same time.